# check changes to a <input type="text" > when value is changing from the back-end using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text-field whose value will be set on the click of a button. I want to detect   when the value of the input field will change. I can't figure out the specific event to fire.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18");
    }

    $(document).on('input', '#mytxtBox', function() {

        alert("Eureka!!!")

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <input id='mytxtBox' type="text">


    <button onclick="myFunction()">Press it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You meant to say when mytxtBox will change the value, you want to alert? Did you tried onchange event?

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya onchange is meant for something else. Here value is getting changed via JavaScript and so onchange will not work here

Comment: @Kajbo not working. can you please try it yourself in JS-Fiddle please.

Comment: I can't seem to understand your question. You click the button, the value changes. When you change the value, click on the button, have the alert popup while keeping the value changed inside the input?

Comment: i have a pretty complex situation, that's why i tried to simplify the question. All i want is to detect the changes to my text-field and the changes are made from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger method to trigger the input event.

```
$('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18").trigger("input");
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: When an event is attached to an element (in your case the input event) it gets fired when the event occurs.

By triggering the event programmatically the event will fire too.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `change` event. first you subscribe the input to the event listener, and add your logic that you want to fire when the event is called. Then you trigger the event after an update. Something like...

```
$(function(){//bind the event listener
    $('#mytxtBox').on('change', function(){
        //do stuff here
    });
})

function myFunction() {
    $('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18");
    $('#mytxtBox').trigger('change');//trigger the event
}
```

Comment: yes, it'll do it but given the complexity of my project, i can't make changes to the code where i am i am writing value to the input field. i need to find out that exact event.

Comment: @RatneshPandey Well post the real code then bud and I'll provide an answer that related to your problem. I can only answer what I see

Comment: my question is simple, is there any event which gets fired when the value of a input field is getting changed through javascript

Comment: @RatneshPandey Simple answer no, if you're changing the field value in your code, you will need to trigger the event in your code. Complex answer... maybe with `MutationObserver` api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the change a `.change()` and it will trigger the `onChange` event

```js
$('#updateValue').on('click', function () {
  $('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18").change();
});

$('#mytxtBox').on('change', function() {
  console.log('abc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='mytxtBox' type="text">
<button id="updateValue"> Press it </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
the alert will pop before the value appear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18").trigger("eureka");
    }
        $(function(){
        $('#mytxtBox').on("eureka", function() {

            alert("Eureka!!!")

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <input id='mytxtBox' type="text">


    <button onclick="myFunction()">Press it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using passing function as a callback to val() method.

Reference:  http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function

```js
function myFunction() {
        $('#mytxtBox').val(function(i ,value){
          alert('hello i am going to change');
          return "2018/12/18";
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='mytxtBox' type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Press it</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are [multiple events](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp) for textbox such as keypress, change, keydown, keyup etc. You can select any as suitable for your goal.

Below example use keypress event:

```js
function fnChangedText() {
  alert("Eureka!!!");
}

function myFunction() {
  $('#mytxtBox').val("2018/12/18");
  $('#mytxtBox').keypress();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='mytxtBox' type="text" onkeypress="fnChangedText()">
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Press it </button>
```

Comment: that's the question :P i can't seem to figure out which event should do it

Comment: In question, You meant to say if value change from button click it also should detect?

Comment: @RatneshPandey I have updated my code. Please let me know your thought.